# sum by group including intermediate groups

Tags: r

I have:

```
df <- data.frame(group=c(1,1,2,4,4,5), value=c(3,1,5,2,3,6))
aggregate(value ~ group, data = df, FUN = 'sum')

  group value
1  1     4
2  2     5
3  4     5
4  5     6
```

is there a way to include intermediate groups to return the below? I realise this could be done by creating a dataframe with all the desired groups and matching in the results from aggregate() but I am hoping there is a cleaner way to do this. it would need to be as fast as using aggregate and only use base r packages - this is due to restrictions in my workplace.

```
  group value
1  1     4
2  2     5
3  3     0
4  4     5
5  5     6
```

Comment: Just do a `merge` and then change the `NA` to 0 with `is.na` i.e. `merge(data.frame(group = 1:5), aggregate(value ~ group, data = df, FUN = 'sum'), all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: Alternatively, `rbind` a data.frame with the missing group values, and aggregate on this, like `aggregate(value ~ group, data =rbind(df, data.frame(group=setdiff(1:5, unique(df$group)), value=0)), FUN = 'sum')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this .

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(group=factor(group, 1:5)) %>%
    complete(group) %>%group_by(group)%>%
    dplyr::summarise(value=sum(value,na.rm = T))


   group value
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      1     4
2      2     5
3      3     0
4      4     5
5      5     6
```

Comment: OP wanted a base R solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with the `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(valuesum = sum(value)) %>% 
  full_join(., expand(df, group = 1:5)) %>% 
  complete(group, fill = list(valuesum = 0))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  group valuesum
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1        4
2     2        5
3     3        0
4     4        5
5     5        6
```

Or a bit more difficult to understand with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[.(group = 1:5), on = 'group', sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), by = .EACHI]
```

Comment: OP wanted a base R solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge`from base R. I've changed the name of your data.frame to `dat`, since `df` is the name of an R function.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
group value
  1     4
  2     5
  4     5
  5     6
", header = TRUE)
str(dat)

res <- aggregate(value ~ group, data = dat, FUN = 'sum')
merge(res, data.frame(group = seq(from = min(res$group), to = max(res$group))), all = TRUE)
```

Note that there will be a `NA`, not a zero. I believe that you should solve that by leaving it as a missing value.